# How to intercept calls to JNI methods that are not listed in native DLL exports?

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, reverse-engineering

I'm in the midst of reverse engineering an MMO that's been built using Java and C++. The game's graphics, networking, physics etc. is implemented via C++ and sit within a single DLL. The game logic is in Java and there's just under 9000 classes. The game logic (Java) interfaces with the engine (C++) via JNI and there is a Stub class that declares 75 native methods that are defined within that DLL. I had the bright idea to insert a proxy DLL that would get called via the game and intercept each call and whatever data is being passed back and forth.

The DLL has only 3 exports:

`_Java_com_aventurine_loader_NativeClassLoader_loadClassBytes@12`

`_Java_spenefett_util_jni_SFJNStub_run@12`

`run`

There is a SFJNStub class that declares the 75 native methods, but I am at a loss at how exactly those methods are called from Java. I know it's something to do with JNI, but this where my lack of experience with JNI is probably getting me stuck as I don't understand exactly how it works.

My proxy DLL includes the `javah`-generated C headers that has all 75 methods defined, but I have no idea how to intercept the non-exported methods.

For example, there is the `recvMiddlewareMessages` method that's declared in Java:

`public native SFMiddlewareMessage[] recvMiddlewareMessages();`

and within the C header:

`JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_spenefett_util_jni_SFJNStub_recvMiddlewareMessages
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);`

and within the DLL (courtesy of IDA):

`push    offset aRecvmiddleware ; "recvMiddlewareMessages"`

But it doesn't point to its own method so finding its actual functionality has been difficult.

I have read up on ways to hide exports and somewhere I read about hiding exports within an abstract interface but I'm not sure that's the case here.

How can I actually interface with the 74 hidden methods?

I forgot to mention that SFJNStub_run is 1 of those 75 methods.

Any help or ideas would definitely be greatly appreciated.

Comment: loadClassBytes does exactly what its name suggests. It loads a class file (already compiled java class) that contains the "native" method interface for Java. It does so by creating its own JVM in C++ and then loading the class file. It MAY also call RegisterNatives to register natives manually. Otherwise the class may already define the native functions. This way, the module does not have to export anything at all because the C++ instance of the JVM registers the function directly without having to get its address via GetProcAddress.

Comment: You can intercept the function on the Java side with the Java ASM library.. This is usually included with your JDK. Otherwise, get an instance to the JNI pointer and grab the function address via that.